# Rename jQuery tab ID from #ui-tabs to something else

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, tabs, lazy-loading

I have jQuery tabs, the content of which is lazy loaded when a tab is clicked. This works great.

```
<div id='tabs'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='url-to-content'><span>John</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='url-to-content'><span>Arnold</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='url-to-content'><span>Dilbert</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to have direct links to specific tabs, so that that particular tab is opened with that link. This is achieved for example by

```
http://www.example.com/tab_page#ui-tabs-2
```

I'd like to have the "ui-tabs-2" replaced by something meaningful, such as in this case

```
http://www.example.com/tab_page#dilbert
```

So basically I'd like to be able to rename the tab IDs from the jQuery default 'ui-tabs-1', 'ui-tabs-2' etc to something else.

That was easy when the content was not lazy loaded, as I created the tab DIVs and IDs myself. But with lazy loading the DIV creation is taken care by jQuery and I can't find a way to affect it.

I have tried placing the anchor in the URL like so

```
        <li><a href='url-to-content#dilbert'><span>Dilbert</span></a></li>
```

Not to much surprise, it didn't work.

I'm aware that the DIV id after the hash # has limitations on what characters are accepted, but that is not a problem. That part is not 100% identical to the tab visible name, but just close.

This is my first question and I've researched the issue for hours, but with no luck. I apologize if this has been discussed before and if so, kindly ask for a link to that question. I haven't been able to find this issue discussed before.

Using jQuery v1.11.1 and jQuery UI - v1.10.4 (both most recent).

---

**Update**:

Based on blgt's idea, I wrote a working solution with the same concept but slightly different implementation. In real life the number of tabs is not the same every time, so I ended up creating a JavaScript object on the fly and then using that to select the tab, like so:

```
var tabs = {
    '#john' : 0,
    '#arnold' : 1,
    '#dilbert' : 2

    // There are more tabs
}

if(window.location.hash in tabs) {
    $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active', tabs[window.location.hash]);
}
```

Comment: so, without deep knowledge of jquery-ui, i guess, the whole widget won't work, as soon, as the tabs got different id's right?
in this case, i'd insert "data-" attribute for my tabs, where i insert the text of my nav links. then, you could use the url() function of ui-tabs to set the url to something with your data- attribute and won't interfere with the jquery-ui selectors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know if there's an HTML way to do this (if there is, it will probably be cleaner), but you can always do it programatically.

[`location.hash`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp) contains the portion of the url after the `#` symbol (including the `#` symbol itself), and [`tabs.options.active`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) can be used to programatically swap tabs. The complete version would look something like the following:

```
$("#tabs").tabs(); // create the tabs widget first
if(window.location.hash === '#John') {
    $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active', 0);
} else if(window.location.hash === '#Arnold') {
    $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active', 1);
} else if(window.location.hash === '#Dilbert') {
    $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active', 2);
}
```

Or use a variable to instantiate the option straight away:

```
var activeTab = window.location.hash === '#John' ? 0 : ... etc;
$("#tabs").tabs({active:activeTab});
```

Comment: Thanks! Not exactly what I was looking for, but at least it works. I ended up creating a JavaScript object with tab names and ID numbers. Unless someone comes up with a simpler solution, I'll mark this one as the correct one. Also, I edited the question to show the current solution.